# Excel - why does my range have overlapping rows in the areas?

Tags: excel, vba

I am returning a Excel.range of a listObject (Excel table), based upon the visible rows, using this kind of syntax (where pLO is a list object):

`Set returnUniqueList = pLO.range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow`

This is happening AFTER I do an advanced filter on a column.  I can see that the advanced filter has worked, and is returning the correct number of rows through visual inspection.

The problem is that the above code snippet returns a range with many areas, which might contain overlapping rows in the areas!  So if I iterate through all the areas in the returned range, I get duplicates.  How can I either only return the visible rows, or filter out the duplicates during the iteration that follows?

EDIT*****************************************************************************************

Erik, some more information regarding the overlapping. the returnUniqueList range above will have numerous 'Area' objects contained within it.  These could number from 1 to n, where 'n' can exceed the number of visible rows in my original table.

Each of these Areas is also a range (so could also contain areas 1..n!!!).  Looking at the rows in these areas, Area(1) could contain identical rows to Area(2)!

END EDIT**********************************************************************************

I can't do an advanced filter to a different range, because I need to return the table worth of filtered table.

I hope this makes sense.

Cheers,

LazzMaTazz

Comment: are you trying to loop through just 1 column's worth of visible rows?

Comment: pLO is a worksheet object? There is no List object in VBA..

Comment: joseph4tw - No I'm filtering on a single column, then looking at each visible row in a table, pulling out information from each row.

Comment: Philip A Barnes - Tables in excel are listObjects: 'Private pLO As Excel.ListObject'

Comment: Can you give a small example of overlapping rows?  Please post some result of `let a = range.address` where "range" is just `pLO.range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` specifically without the `.EntireRow`) ?   When the input source to `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` is a single column, i've not to date seen the issue you're having, so I'm wondering if the .EntireRow addition is gumming up the works.

Comment: Hi Erik.  I'll try to describe it, as I don't think I can post meaningful visual feedback to make this obvious.  I'll edit the above post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've come up with to this problem is to create a new worksheet in my workbook, and copy the filtered table into this new worksheet.

This always (in my testing with various tables so far) seems to copy the filtered table from the source worksheet into contiguous rows in the temporary destination worksheet.  This then returns a range object with a single 'area', which can be used reliably.

I have to be careful to:

- make sure I clean the temporary worksheet up when I'm finished working with the data
- clear the temporary worksheet cells after each operation so old data doesn't cause me problems.

  ```
  Private Function copyToNewWorkSheet() As Excel.range

   ' call this when the sourcesheet (pWkSht) is already filtered.
  Dim myWkBk As New Excel.Workbook
  Dim tempWs As New Excel.Worksheet

  ' if the first time this is called, create the new worksheet
  If WorksheetExists("TempWorkSheet") Then
      Set tempWs = pMyWkBk.Worksheets("TempWorkSheet")
  Else
      Set tempWs = pMyWkBk.Worksheets.Add(After:=pMyWkBk.Worksheets(pMyWkBk.Worksheets.Count))
      tempWs.Name = "TempWorkSheet"
  End If

  ' clear the temp worksheet contents
  tempWs.Cells.Clear

  ' reselect my source worksheet (which is already filtered)
  pWkSht.Select

  ' it falls over sometimes if this isn't here - any thoughts???
  pWkSht.range("A1", pWkSht.Cells(pWkSht.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Select

  ' copy the required from the course worksheet, using information from the table (pLO) on the worksheet
  pWkSht.range("A1", pWkSht.Cells(pLO.range.Areas(pLO.range.Areas.Count).rows.Count, "A")).Resize(, pLO.range.Columns.Count).Copy tempWs.range("A1")

  ' return the 'clean' range from the temporary worksheet
  Set copyToNewWorkSheet = tempWs.range("A1", tempWs.Cells(tempWs.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(, pLO.range.Columns.Count)

  End Function
  ```

I can upload a workbook if anyone would like to see the solution in full.  This problem has taken me a few days to solve - so please feel free to ask!

LazzMaTazz

Answer (score 2):

Try same without the `.EntireRow` as in:

```
'Set returnUniqueList = pLO.range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
 Set returnUniqueList = pLO.range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

and see what the Areas are, and if there are yet any overlapping rows in this result.

Comment: Hi Erik, I tried that, but it only returns a range comprising the column I currently have selected.  I think I may have come up with an answer, which I'll post now.